# How to make changes in this template to add more images

Tags: html, css

I have this code, with HTML and CSSS, and as you can see the template is set up to only have 3 images in the carrousel. But i want to add all the images that I want. (You can see how I added more

with the images) but, how do i make the arrow buttons appears? Any help please?

```
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/we0zn0yf1z1hgla/codigoinstag.css?dl=0" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="postig"><div class="headig multfo"><div class="userimgp"><div class="imgus-postig"><img src="profileImage"></div><div class="user-postig"><strong>MinJae</strong><br/>Varana Hotel Krabi</div></div><div class="pnt-postig"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></div></div><div class="sp-slideshow"><input id="button-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-1" checked="checked" /><label for="button-1" class="button-label-1"></label> <input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" /> <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label><input id="button-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-3" /><label for="button-3" class="button-label-3"></label></label><label for="button-1" class="sp-arrow sp-a1"></label><label for="button-2" class="sp-arrow sp-a2"></label><label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label><div class="sp-content" style="position:relative; top:-25px;"><div class="sp-parallax-bg"><ul class="sp-slider clearfix"><li><img src="Image"></li> <li><img src="Image"><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li><li><img src="Image"></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="foot-postig"><div class="hheart"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></div> <i class="far fa-comment"></i> <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> <i class="far fa-bookmark"></i></div><div class="coment-postig"><div class="mg-postig"><strong>780k Me gusta</strong></div><div class="post-user-ig"><strong> MinJae</strong> Texto caption debajo de la foto<hash>#Hastag</hash> </div></div></div><div class="cred"><a href="http://bettyleg.tumblr.com">bettyleg</a></div>

<style>.sp-slideshow {background-color: white;} .postbody .content ul, .postbody .content ol {margin-left:0px!important;} .postig{width:400px; max-height:600px; margin:10px auto; border:1px solid #eee;} .headig{height:45px; background:#fff; padding:7px; border-bottom:1px solid #eee;} .imgus-postig{background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%,#d6249f 60%,#285AEB 90%); width:44px; height:44px; padding:2px; border-radius:180px;} .imgus-postig img{border:2px solid #fff;width:40px; height:40px; border-radius:180px;} .user-postig{position:relative; top:-37px; left:60px; font-family:arial; font-size:13px; text-align:12px; color:#444;} .pnt-postig{float:right; margin-top:-65px; right:20px; position:relative; color:#444;} .foot-postig{height:20px; border-top:1px solid #eee; padding:10px; padding-left:15px; background:#fff;} .foot-postig i{font-size:20px; color:#555;} .foot-postig .fa-heart, .foot-postig .fa-comment{margin-right:14px;} .hheart:hover .fa-heart{color:red!important; font-weight:900!important;} .hheart{display:inline-block;} .coment-postig{max-height:80px; background:#fff; font-family:arial; padding:5px 15px; font-size:14px; color:#333; padding-bottom:20px;} .mg-postig{height:23px; font-size:13px; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; margin-bottom:10px;} .post-user-ig hash{color:blue;} .cred{margin:0px auto; margin-top:-5px; width:280px; text-align:center;} .cred a{text-decoration:none; color:#888; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:8px; font-family:arial; letter-spacing:2px;} .foot-postig .fa-bookmark{float:right; position:relative; right:10px;} .sp-slider > li img {height: auto!important;width: 100%!important;} 
</style>
```

I tried to add
`<input id="button-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="sp-selector-2" /> <label for="button-2" class="button-label-2"></label>`
By changing the number 2 for 4 and so on.
Also triied to add
`<label for="button-3" class="sp-arrow sp-a3"></label>`
By changing the number 3 for 4 and so on.

Also in the CSS I tried:

```
.sp-selector-1:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a2, .sp-selector-2:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a3, .sp-selector-3:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a4 {right: 15px;display: block;background-position: top right;}.sp-selector-2:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a1, .sp-selector-3:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a2, sp-selector-4:checked ~ .sp-arrow.sp-a2 { left: 15px;display: block;background-position: top left;}
```

But It is not working.

Comment: Consult the documentation for the slideshow plugin or library. Include the name and version of the library in your question if you cant find the documentation.